# Need to find from which website the had been redirected

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Hi guys i had a tie up with another company, when a user redirect from my website to my tie my up company and fills out the form from there how could i able to find the count?

Comment: you could look at the HTTP referer, but its unreliable, they should tag the ref link

Comment: could you explain more

Comment: Voting to close this question as it shows no research effort nor is it programming related.  Please take a moment to look at the SO help section and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could check at the [Referer HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) :

But note that the Referer is sent by the browser, which means :

- It can be disabled (it's not mandatory, and is just an additionnal information that the browser can send)
- It can be faked (i.e. anyone can send anything -- even some SQL injection, or XSS injection, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

it's to simple
Create table in db with name "redirect_history" with fileds id, count, timestamp;
create a php file with INSERT Query like this and add a button under form and set action to insert_redirect_history.php

insert_redirect_history.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$count = 0;
$last_count= "SELECT * FROM redirect_history ORDER BY count DESC"

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $last_count);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $insert_count = $row["count"]+1;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO redirect_history (id, count)
VALUES (NULL, '$insert_count')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo header('Location: http://www.tieupcompanyurl.com/');;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Let me know if you find answer helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique URL for it. When a user clicks on the url first take the user to the page where you can access the IP address address of the visitor and save it to the database and after that redirect the user to the to your tie up company's site with a uninque id with the url where on the company's site form you can access that unique id attached with the url so whenever any user registers through your link then they can have that unique id store in the database which is generated by your site. So at the end the company and you can share that data and can match how many users have actually registered through your site.
Hope this helps.